# Power Adapter for Traveling to Scotland (I live in the US)

Tags: usa, power, scotland

I live in the US, and will be traveling to Scotland. I will need to charge my laptop and phone (macbook and iPhone if it matters) while I am there, and I have been receiving some mixed advice about what kind of power adapter and/or convertor I need to get. All my devices have the standard US type B power plugs, while in the UK, as I understand it, they use type G.

- Some people have said that all I need is a cheap little adapter that converts between type B and type G plugs, like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072K3Y9KH). They say that my devices "can handle" the difference in voltage.
- Others say that I need a fancy converter to convert between the different voltages in the two countries.

Which is correct, and why?

Comment: @MarkJohnson when I moved from USA to Europe I had to buy a step up transformer for 220/240v powered devices such as TV & deathlike. However,laptops already have a transformer in the charger, so no extra hardware was necessary

Comment: @Mawg PC's have them as well but must be manually set. Checking the label (meantioned elsewhere) is important. So checking each device is needed and never assuming that the plug adapter will convert the voltage was my point.

Comment: The adapter you have linked to is *unfused* and is *illegal* to use in the UK. You would be better to wait until you get to the UK and buy one here that complies with safety regulations. They're in all large supermarkets, Boots and Argos stores. Eg https://www.argos.co.uk/product/8556295

Comment: @smci it is actually true that many desktop PC's these days still have a small red switch in the back that you must manually switch to the proper voltage. I never really thought about why computers have this, but now I know! That said, you are right that I've never seen this on a laptop.

Comment: @Bunji: no, only desktops, laptops pretty much never do. Yes, desktops may need to be manually switched, to avoid sending the power supply up in smoke. You asked about a laptop.

Comment: @smci I am the OP

Comment: I echo @Owain's comment. DO NOT BUY THE ADAPTOR YOU LINKED. Wait till you get to the UK then buy one from a reputable source. Electricity in homes is more dangerous in the UK than it is in the US due to higher voltage and much higher current wiring, so extra safety measures are normally present on our plugs — which won't be present on anything you can buy in the US. You'll be spending a little more most likely but it's worth it for the peace of mind that you aren't going to shock yourself or burn your hotel down...

Comment: @Muzer I actually already own one that is fused (purchased by someone in the UK), so no need to worry about me. I just used the link for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Your question has ambiguity around "devices": **if "device" = laptop** then no you don't need a voltage converter (but do obviously still need an adapter); laptops have universal voltage converters. Only **if "device" =  shaver/kettle/heater/desktop/other power appliance** might you need a voltage converter.

Comment: @smci no, I will not delete it. Electricity is **dangerous**. Allways check carefully before usage. Most PC's  have the switch inside, sometimes outside. In my 35 years as technician I have only seen it blow once where 200 PC's were donated to a school. The switch was outside, thus the decision had already been made to glue them up. While testing one with open cover a 9 year old came in, saw the red switch on a black background and used his small finger to switch it over. The result was a black mushroom cloud and a blown fuse....

Comment: Do that in a hotel and probably the whole floor will be blown out. In a pension the house. So @smci it is **not ridiculous**. With Electricity never assume anything.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: "Do what" in a hotel? You seem to be constructing bizarre strawmen that the question never asked about. Noone travels with a suitcase of desktop PCs, so that's not at issue. Laptops have universal transformers for precisely that reason.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Almost certainly, each AC to DC converter you have will support both UK and US voltages, and you do not need a voltage converter.

To be absolutely sure, look at the back of your laptop's charger and your AC-to-USB plug. There should be a label that, among other things, specifies supported input voltages and AC frequencies. If it says something like "100-240V" and "50-60Hz" you only need a simple plug type converter.

Comment: As a Scot who lives in the US but often travels back to Scotland, I endorse this answer :) Unless you have some weird knockoff, the Apple chargers will have no problem with the voltages. My preference is plug convertor that has a couple of USB sockets built in.

Comment: The only thing I have that does not support 100-240 is my electric toothbrush.  Laptop charger, phone chargers, line to USB converter, all do 100-240

Comment: The vast majority of electronics support 100-240 (since they're transforming the voltage anyway); things that don't tend to be more mechanical appliances, like that electric toothbrush, or hairdryers, toasters etc, that apply the voltage to a motor, heater etc (though I think a growing number of these do support 100-240, maybe because they increasingly include some electronics)

Answer (score 3):

The [Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201700) states:

> You should use the appropriate wattage power adapter for your Mac notebook. You can use a compatible higher wattage adapter without issue, but it won't make your computer charge faster or operate differently. Lower wattage adapters don't provide enough power.

The adapters are rated at a higher voltage and should be fine.

Comment: I have this kit, but it won't work to charge an iPhone, unless you're charging the phone by connecting it to the MacBook (possible, but cumbersome). This travel kit *does* work for the iPad charger, which will also work with an iPhone (USB connector).

Comment: @Mike is correct: one can't use any of these to charge an iPhone directly. But I always travel with a MacBook Air, its power supply, and a simple plug adapter that'll work in the country I'm in. When I get where I'm going, I plug in the computer, If the phone needs juice, I can plug it into the computer or use the Apple wall wart I also carry in my goody bag.

Comment: Lifehack: The internal connector used by Apple to attach these various plugs into their power bricks is compatible with a standard [IEC C7/C8 "figure-8" plug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_60320#C7/C8_coupler). Any power cord with (e.g.) a UK plug at one end and a C7 connector at the other (like [any one of these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/slp/figure-8-power-lead/rokja7tf3pss7ya)) can be used to charge your Mac by pulling the "duckhead" off the power brick and plugging the cord in its place. It looks ugly, but works fine.

Comment: Ah overpriced crap that can be had without the brand name, what and apple thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

## 1) For your MacBook adapter: you need **neither**. Just simply buy a UK duckhead for your MacBook, already.

Either:

- the outrageously overpriced official "Apple World Travel Adapter set" (which is just five outrageously overpriced duckheads in a box), or
- (unofficial third-party) individual duckheads (you can't find these on Amazon, only on eBay, for (cough, cough) legal reasons). Yes, the UK duckhead will have an earth prong but probably won't be fused. So don't leave it plugged in overnight or unattended.

Context: I just got back from Europe with my MacBook, and before I went I spent the princely total of US$5.50 on UK + EU duckheads (+ $15 for the world travel adapter). I researched this heavily before I went. Apple egregiously abuses so-called "intellectual-property" laws to legally intimidate competitors from selling duckheads in the US, i.e. a piece of plastic with a few metal bits, to preserve their obscene margins.

## 2) For your phone charger, **no you do not need a voltage converter**, you just get an adapter (world travel adapter).

A neat and compact solution is a **world travel adapter with built-in (twin) USB**, better still if it's twin 2.2A USB; you can even get quad-USB if you have lots of devices. These are the ones with multi-type A/B/C/G with quick-slide retractable prongs, they're lightweight, compact and retractable so they fit nicely into carry-on baggage, good for a quick use at the boarding gate, cafe etc. Ceptics is a superb brand. Just be gentle with the mechanism when you retract one type of prong and extend the other.

As to the ambiguities in the phrasing of your question: **if "device" = laptop** then no you don't need a voltage converter (but do obviously still need an adapter); laptops have universal voltage converters. Only **if "device" =  shaver/kettle/heater/desktop/other power appliance** might you need an actual voltage converter. But that wasn't what the question asked about.

Comment: This answer brought to you by the "CE" and "CCC" certification marks...

Comment: @Harper: you seem to have first upvoted this then downvoted it. Why? If you have a valid criticism then say so. I didn't say "buy stuff that isn't CCC/CE certified". I did point out Apple enjoys an obscene margin on its own-brand stuff.

Comment: @smci: If I recall correctly, I've seen Harper _denounce_ the CE mark as a sign of particularly low quality. I think he's trying to criticize you for _recommending_ CE-marked adapters, which he considers crap.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I said nothing at all about certification, so if that's why he downvoted, that's unreasonable. I'm not into "device nationalism"...

Comment: @Harper: your previous comments were deleted. An Apple duckhead is literally a piece of plastic, explain if you can how certification is specifically relevant to that, for anything other than preserving Apple's profit margins. I'm still not seeing any valid point from you, and we've asked you several times already.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the earlier.  If you are mad at me I very much apologize!  **I never downvoted your post** but have not upvoted either.  This is my standard treatment for posts where I disagree but respect the arguments.  I concur a DV for that reason would be unfair.  I have no idea why my comments were deleted (don't recall doing it).

Comment: @Harper: well if your recurring point is "CCC certification is near-worthless, and nowhere near the standard of CE certification" then please say that clearly. Your comment can still be read as a criticism and encouragement to downvote, which seems unreasonable in the specific context I give.

Comment: As far as "device nationalism", there is a common misconception between "brand loyalty" and "certified as safe".  Take Square D breaker panels. An Eaton BR, GE QH, or Siemens QT will "fit" *but is not safe*.  People misinterpret my warning as brand loyalty; as if I'm saying you should only use Square D, like a cleerleader.  NO! I will gleefully recommend an Eaton CL, Eaton CHQ or Siemens QD *because **those** types are designed **for** Square D panels, and a competent testing lab has tested them to extremes in Square D panels, and certified them as safe*.   Square D does not approve, natch.

Comment: In fact, both CCC and CE marks are sure to be counterfeit given your mail order sourcing.  The problem with your posting is *not only do you care absolutely not at all about product safety*, **you are positively gleeful about disregarding it**, and then, in these comments, you have the audacity to assert that ***product safety doesn't even exist, plastic is plastic, and all disagrement with your position is Apple apologism***. Consider what you are saying.

Comment: @Harper: stop with the misplaced attacks about certification. You don't know what I actually think, you didn't even bother to ask before making wild assumptions, and you are conflating separate issues into a false dichotomy: either we each must be for dangerous unsafe or counterfeits devices, or we must be for spurious trademark lawsuits all the way to strongarm competitors - and no middle ground. Clearly a sensible solution should be in the middle. Meanwhile, all of us in the real world have a de-facto dichotomy between eBay or Apple Store(/Amazon).

Comment: @Harper: and I never asserted that "product safety doesn't even exist", you keep wilfully misrepresenting me, that's abuse of SO rules, I'm warning you to stop. I keep pointing out that **putting a third-party plastic duckhead on a genuine Apple power adapter is not the strawman scenario you keep pretending it is**. It's not like I bought my actual power adapter itself from a no-name outfit with no certification. I think you don't understand what a 'duckhead' is, do you? It's only the tiny connector part. There are no power electronics in it whatsoever. Do you understand that?

Answer (score 1):

### Look at the device.  If it says 120-240V, you're all set

It may say a wider range like 100-240V (or 90-264V which is that +/-10%).  100V comes from Japan, if you're wondering.

Your Apple branded chargers will all be multi-voltage. Third party chargers may vary, but in all probability, they're multi-voltage too because of the magic of switching power supplies.

Since they are multi-voltage, all you need is an adapter to physically connect the US prongs to the UK socket.  This device will contain only copper and plastic.  Beware cheap Cheese junk; look for the mark of competent testing labs such as UL, CSA, BSI, TUV, ETL, etc.

*Most things care about voltage. Some things also care about frequency. So check each device individualy*.

### Any run-of-the-mill IEC C7 cord will also do

You've seen C7. It's is the little socket used on everyone else's laptop power supplies, tape recorders, projectors etc.

On some Apple adapters, you can remove the plug portion. That exploses an inlet* for IEC C7.  You've seen C7 before.  **You can use any run-of-the-mill IEC C7 cord**, or you can get different Apple plug modules for different countries that snap in just like the original, if you don't want to drag [a cord](https://images.app.goo.gl/bYq92yyaapMDVpvC7) around.

### The standard, bulky UK socket is called a BS1363

It's much more productive to search for "BS1363" than "G".   So for instance you might search for a C7 to BS1363 cord.

Note a couple unique things about BS1363 that differ from the compact US sockets:

- The BS1363 socket has a switch on it.  If the socket is dead, try the switch.
- The BS1363 **plug** has a **fuse** in it. *Yeah. Seriously.* So if nothing else is working, check the fuse.

---

* Technically speaking, an "inlet for IEC C7" is C8, but let's not confuse the matter. C7 is what you need.